# I would like to keep my computer organized and so i want my pipenv enviorments in a folder in my documents named 'virtual_enviorments' f

Tags: python, windows, pip, pipenv

I want to keep my new computer organized and use pipenv, how can i change the default location of a virtual environment location to a folder in my documents, so when i run "pipenv shell" in a project folder it will put the location of the actual virtual env into the document instead of hiding it in folders/folders/folders...

I tried to look at the docs and I couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: Personally I would consider organising by having each project have its own directory, with the venv/dependencies relevant to that project living inside said directory. Can't really go wrong and mix up which is for which project that way.

Comment: [Custom Virtual Environment Location](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#custom-virtual-environment-location)

Answer (score 1):

The [location of the virtual environments](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#custom-virtual-environment-location) can be controlled by setting the `WORKON_HOME` environment variable.

> Pipenv automatically honors the `WORKON_HOME` environment variable, if it is set, so you can tell pipenv to store your virtual environments wherever you want, e.g.:
>
> ```
> export WORKON_HOME=~/.venvs
> ```

It also supports @ch4rl1e97's recommendation:

> In addition, you can also have Pipenv stick the virtualenv in project/.venv by setting the `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` environment variable.

The value of the variable should be one of `1`, `true`, `yes`, or `on`. (See https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration-with-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a custom Virtual Environment Location for your virtual environments , for your case is in the native DOcuments folder ,

Pipenv always sticks to the WORKON_HOME environment variable , given it has been set , then you can dictate pipenv to store your virtual environments wherever you want.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line on the file:

```bash
export WORKON_HOME=~/Documents/MyVirtualEnv/.venvs
```

Then type to activate it

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

NB: make sure you have the folder " MyVirtualEnv " , in your documents folder
For more information check here : https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html